# How to boost relevance of Search API solr with the value of a certain field?

Tags: search

I am using [Search API solr](https://drupal.org/project/search_api_solr) on my site. To get better search results I would like to boost the relevance by the value of a certain numeric field. 
Say, all items have a field A, which is numeric. Now I want to boost the relevance of those itemes by the value of field a, so that, if As value is higher the relevance of the item becomes higher too.
I have absolutely no idea how to do this. Maybe with

```
hook_search_api_solr_query_alter()
```

But I did not find documentation how to use it. Please hint me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

[hook_apachesolr_query_alter($query)](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!apachesolr!apachesolr.api.php/function/hook_apachesolr_query_alter/7) alter the query after it's prepared and cached.

As per example given in documentation which I found, you can use this hook in similar way to other query_alter hook. E.g -

```
function hook_apachesolr_query_alter($query) {
  //Adding one more filter.
  $query->addFilter("is_uid", 1);

  // Only search titles.
  $query->replaceParam('qf', 'label');
}
```

Find the documentation by clicking on the mentioned hook name by me.

**EDITED--**

Sorry for giving example of other hook of apache solr module. You can find documentation of your hook here [hook_search_api_solr_query_alter()](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!search_api_solr!search_api_solr.api.php/function/hook_search_api_solr_query_alter/7).

You can find a small snippet for example of this hook like --

```
function hook_search_api_solr_query_alter(array &$call_args, SearchApiQueryInterface $query) {
  if ($query->getOption('foobar')) {
    $call_args['params']['foo'] = 'bar';
  }
}
```

Eric has wrote a nice [article](http://ericlondon.com/tag/hook_search_api_solr_query_alter) with example of this hook.

Comment: Her question refers to Search API solr module and not to Apachesolr module.

Comment: @user5950 - I have edited the answer...thanks for pointing out.

Comment: Use this to boost by a numeric field, where `is_field_priority` is the solr name for an indexed Drupal field. `$call_args['params']['bf'][] = 'sum(1,product(2000,is_field_priority))'`